# Concatenating strings to unsigned long keeping a fixed dimension result

Tags: arduino

I have a token stored as an String representation of an hex number:

```
String tokenStored = "ABCD1234ABABFFFF";
```

I also have an unsigned long number as follows:

```
unsigned long noun = 12345;
```

I need to concatenate *tokenStored* + *noun* and have a char array result of a fixed length, but I cant decide how to approach the problem in an elegant way. I came up with this possible -ugly- solution:

Keep *tokenStored* as String, then convert noun from decimal to hex, and then to string. Fill the remaining spaces (if any) of the result string with "0" to keep the length to always 8 chars, so 12345 will be 0x3039 then "3039" then "00003039". This way I can concatenate and have "ABCD1234ABABFFFF00003039", always fixed to 24 chars. This solution will involve masking, and I'm not an expert. What do you think of this approach, please provide examples.

Comment: Do you have any requirements on the format of concatenation? Should it left-pad `noun` with zeros or it can also do something else, like left-padding the concatenation itself?

Comment: @yeputons It could be something, but ideally for readability I think left-pad will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is the way to go - it has same interface as standard streams (`cin`/`cout`/`ifstream`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string tokenStored = "ABCD1234ABABFFFF";    
    unsigned long noun = 12346;

    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::setfill('0') // left-pad with zeros
           << std::setw(16) // left-pad following output to 16 chars
           << tokenStored
           << std::setw(8) << std::hex << std::uppercase // now left-pad to 8
           << noun;

    std::string result = stream.str(); // get stream's buffer
    std::cout << result << ", length is " << result.length();
    return 0;
}
```

Another possibility is to go with C approach and use `snprintf` which is safe and typesafe, but looks shorter:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string tokenStored = "ABCD1234ABABFFFF";    
    unsigned long noun = 12346;

    char buf[25]; // 1 extra char for null terminator
    // 's' is for 'string', 'X' is for heXadecimal in upper case
    // '0' means 'pad with zeros', numbers 16 and 8 are padding width
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%016s%08lX", tokenStored.c_str(), noun);
    std::string result = buf;

    std::cout << result << ", length is " << result.length();
    return 0;
}
```

Here you have to worry about correct `buf` size, correct specifiers for `unsigned long` (if you change the type, you have to change the specifier as well) and it won't work it anything but primitive types.